# Am I understanding this function correctly?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

A kind of family tree can be represented by the following Haskell datatype:

```
type Name   = String
type Born   = Int
data Family = Fam Name Born [Family]
```

Here is an example Family:

```
duck :: Family
duck = Fam "Uncle Scrooge" 1898
                    [ Fam "Donald" 1932 [] ,
                      Fam "Ronald" 1933
                              [ Fam "Huey" 1968 [] ,
                                Fam "Duey" 1968 [] ,
                                Fam "Louie" 1968 [] ]
                    ]
```

This value represents the male line of the duck family where Uncle Scrooge, born in 1898, had two sons, Donald and Ronald. Ronald has three children. Donald has no children, and Ronald has no grandchildren.

My task is to describe what is happening in the following function:

```
parent :: Name -> Family -> [Name]            
parent n fam = par [] fam
  where 
        par fathers (Fam child _ cs)
           | child == n = fathers ++ otherFathers
           | otherwise  = otherFathers
                where otherFathers = concatMap (par [child]) cs
                                  -- concat [par [child] c | c <- cs ]
```

which given a name of a person and a family tree, finds all the possible parents of the person in the tree. So, for example,

```
*Main> parent "Duey" duck
[Ronald]

*Main> parent "Uncle Scrooge" duck
[]

*Main> parent "Bob" duck
[]
```

If the child’s name appears several times in the family tree then there could be more than one possible parent.

So here's my try:

Let's say I want to solve `parent "Duey" duck`. The first thing that's going to happen is that I am going to run the `par` function, with the inputs `[]` (an empty list) and `duck` (which has the datatype `Family`).

Here's where I start to get confused so please bear with me.

So what does the `par` function do? As far as my understanding goes, the `par` function takes a list and a `Family`. It then checks if the name that the `Family` originates from is equal to the name we used as input for `parent`. If they are equal then it appends the inputted list and `otherFathers`. If the names aren't equal, it just returns otherFathers. So in our case so far it checks if `"Uncle Scrooge"` is equal to "Duey". Since it isn't, it returns `otherFathers`.

So what does `otherFathers` do? As far as I understand it maps the `par` function with `["Child"]` on the next branch of the family. So in our case it runs `par ["Uncle Scrooge"]` on the families origintating from `"Donald"` and from `"Ronald"`. Since neither of these are equal to `"Duey"` the same process will repeat but with `par ["Donald"] []` and `par ["Ronald"] cs`. Since "Donald" has no family, the function can't continue. `par ["Ronald"] cs` will repeat the smae process as before with `"Huey"` and `"Louie"`, where the function can't continue since they don't have any children. But with "Duey" since this name is equal to the first inputted name, it will add "Ronald" to otherFathers and then return ["Ronald"] ++ otherFathers as the result, since there are no more families to check.

Here are my questions:

1. Do I understand the code correctly? Am I missing something?
2. If you where going to build this `parent` function, what would be your 
   strategy?

A thousand thanks to anyone taking the time to read and reply, I am truly very grateful. Cheers.

I am very new to this website, so I would love any feedback on formatting etc.

Comment: What is the "this" in "it will add this to `otherFathers` and then return this as the result"? I think you have everything basically right, except possibly that very last clause, depending on what you mean by "this" (and "add", I guess).

Comment: @DanielWagner Yeah I see how that is confusing. I mean that since "Duey" is equal to the first inputted name. It will execute the operation ["Ronald"] ++ otherFathers. I changed it now in the original text! :) Hopefully easier to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have correctly understood what's happening.

I think I wouldn't write the code this way. It bothers me that it uses a list with either 0 or 1 element (the `fathers` argument to `par`) to indicate whether the recursion is "in its first step" or not. It seems much more straightforward to me to treat each node of the tree independently, emitting the name at the node once for each child that matches the person we're looking for. After applying this idea and a few other aesthetic tweaks, I think I would put it this way:

```
name :: Family -> Name
name (Fam n _ _) = n

parent :: Name -> Family -> [Name]
parent n = go where
    go (Fam par _ cs) = concatMap (\c -> [par | name c == n] ++ go c) cs
```